# How to pass parameter to JsonSerializer?

Tags: java, jackson, jax-rs, dropwizard, jsonserializer

I have a simple data service :

```
@GET
public Data getData(@QueryParam("id") Long id) {
  Data data = dataService.getData(id);
  return data;
}
```

And a matching `DataSerializer` that implements `JsonSerializer<Data>` :
The `DataSerializer` is registered to Jackson via :

```
simpleModule.addSerializer(Data.class , dataSerializer);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(simpleModule);
```

It works well.
But today , I want to add another `Locale` parameter , and hope the `DataSerializer` to output correspondent content :

```
@GET
public Data getData(@QueryParam("id") Long id , @QueryParam("locale") Locale locale)
```

The '`Data`' itself contains various locale variations , and I hope to get the assigned locale output.

But when I get the `locale` from the parameter , I don't know how to pass the `locale` value to the `DataSerializer` …

Is there anyway to achieve this ?

Except this solution :

```
Data data = dataService.getData(id.get() , locale);
```

which is not what I want.

It seems `ThreadLocal` is the only way to achieve this , but I feel that is ugly. Any other feasible solutions ?

Thanks.

Environments : dropwizard-0.7.0-rc2 , jackson-core:jar:2.3.1

===================== updated ==========

reply to @andrei-i :

Because my data itself already contains various locale versions.
for example :

```
Data helloData = dataService.get("hello");
helloData.getName(Locale.English) == "Hello";
helloData.getName(Locale.France) == "Bonjour";
helloData.getName(Locale.Germany) == "Hallo";
```

I want to directly pass the locale from URL to JsonSerializer , to get one version of the data presentation.

And there 'may' be other version (not just locale) , so , inheriting Data mixing Locale is not considered.

Comment: Why not making your Data class locale-aware: introduce a LocaleData class that has the same fields as Data, but translates the translatable stuff?

Comment: hi @@andrei-i  , I replied in the content. Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

I know that this is not a new question but here is what I came up with facing the similar problem:

1. created custom annotation:

   ```
   @Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
   public @interface JsonLocalizable {

     public String localizationKey();
   }
   ```
2. Jackson serializer:

   ```
    public class LocalizingSerializer extends StdSerializer<String> implements ContextualSerializer {

         private String localizationKey;

         public LocalizingSerializer() {
           super(String.class);
         }

         public LocalizingSerializer(String key) {
           super(String.class);

           this.localizationKey = key;
         }

         @Override
         public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonGenerationException {

           String localizedValue = //.... get the value using localizationKey

           jgen.writeString(localizedValue);
         }

         @Override
         public JsonSerializer<?> createContextual(SerializerProvider prov, BeanProperty property) throws JsonMappingException {

           String key = null;
           JsonLocalizable ann = null;

           if (property != null) {
             ann = property.getAnnotation(JsonLocalizable.class);
           }

           if (ann != null) {
             key = ann.localizationKey();
           }

           //if key== null??

           return new LocalizingSerializer(key);
         }
       }
   ```
3. Annotate the field you want to localize:

   ```
   public class TestClass {

       @JsonSerialize(using = LocalizingSerializer.class)
       @JsonLocalizable(localizationKey = "my.key")
       private String field;

       public String getField() {
         return this.field;
       }

       public void setField(String field) {
         this.field = field;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Following needs to be added in the custom annotation @JacksonAnnotation for it to be available in the BeanProperty parameter of the createContextual method.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1.** In your JAX-RS implementation register your own implementation of [MessageBodyWriter](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html#d0e5293) for JSON requests. Probably your implementation will extend Jackson. Also it might be possible that you will have to unregister Jackson. In a `MessageBodyWriter` you can inject a [UriInfo](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.0.GA/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html) instance using the `@Context` annotation, and with it you can get any request parameter.

**Solution 2.** Change the architecture of your `Data`, so that it is locale-aware. For example, create a setter `setLocale()` which will change the returned data, if the locale was set.

Comment: H, `DataMessageBodyWriter extends JsonSerializer implements MessageBodyWriter<Data>` seems good . But I have to `@Inject JacksonJsonProvider` and `@Inject Provider<ObjectMapper>` . In the injection of `Provider<ObjectMapper>` , it will cause circular dependency (because `ObjectMapperProvider implements Provider<ObjectMapper>` itself needs `DataMessageBodyWriter` to be injected)  . I know it is very complicated , maybe solution 2 is easier.

Comment: It seems complicated as you explained it, but I meant something easier: extend directly `DataMessageBodyWriter extends JacksonJsonProvider` and simply add an if condition in the extended `writeTo` method before calling super, for handling your `Data` type.

Comment: I use the Solution 2. … Well , I don't thinks it is the best solution. Because in JsonSerializer , there is no mechanism to get info from the Resource layer. 

When in the Resource layer , there is no way to assign the output decorator of a POJO. (in my example , the decorating parameter is a locale )

Comment: But did you try my idea to extend directly JacksonJsonProvider where you access to the whole request?